# In Clean architecture MVVM where transform objects to adapter?

Tags: android, mvvm, clean-architecture

So, let's suppose I have an adapter with multiples view types and what I receive from server api is just a list and I have to transform in my adapter objects.

Example:
I have a list of persons that have a type associated,  let's think 1 and 2, and I want to show in my recyclerview an header between different types.

So, I have a fragment - view model - use case - repository (request to api)

My adapter expect a lista of persons.
Let's think Person is a interface, and person1 and person2, implements that.

Final, I receive from server a list with objects PersonApi, that have a type as parameter and I have to convert that to my adapter objects.

Where I should do this transformation?
Repository?
Use case?
View model?

My guess, should be on use case.

Edit:
Added a chart
[image]

Comment: Btw: It's MVVM not MVMM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the fact that the full implementation of clean architecture has lots of layers, model mappings, ... which makes it hard to implement. So, we can take advantage of a simplified version, just like you mentioned in your question in three layers; `Data`, `Domain` and `Presentation`.

It is nice to have specific data models for each layer, but it's also ok to share `Domain` models with `Presentation` as well. It means that you need just one step of data mapping, which happens between `Data` and `Domain` right at the adjacency point.
Since the repository is the bridge between `Data` and `Domain`, it is the right place to map models.

Definition of repositories should be part of `Domain`, and the implementation inside `Data`. This way `Data` layer provides exactly what `Domain` layer expects. Keep in mind that `Domain` **MUST NOT** know anything of `Data` layer and its implementation. So, if you are implementing your layers in different gradle modules, you should have a dependency to `Domain` inside `Data` module, and not the other way round.

A simplified implementation of classes could be like the following:

**Domain:**

```
interface Person

class Person1() : Person

class Person2() : Person

interface PersonRepository {
    fun getPersons(): List<Person>
}

class GetPersonsUseCase(val repository: PersonRepository) {
    fun execute(): List<Person> {
        return repository.getPersons()
    }
}
```

**Data:**

```
class PersonRepositoryImpl(val service: PersonService): PersonRepository {
    fun getPersons(): List<Person> {
        val list: List<PersonEntity> = service.getPersons()
        return list.map { it.toPerson() }
    }
}

PersonEntity.toPerson(): Person {
    return ... // create an instance of Person1 or Person2 based on requirements.
}
```

Comment: Just asking, why definition of repositories should be on domain? It means that definition of use cases(domain) should be on presentation too?

Comment: Actually, the aim of clean-arch is to isolate the domain (business logic) from other layers. So, it is the domain itself that defines how to interact with data or presentation. In the case of data, it defines repository abstractions, and in the case of presentation, it could define interactors. So, everything related to the domain remains inside the domain and not in other layers. You can find one of the best practices here: https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

As per the basic rule for Clean architecture that every layer is completely independent from other layer. so here you have to write business logic either in Model class or View model class based on the scenario, publish this unique attribute value to view(adapter). Please find below the high level architecture diagram:

[image]

Comment: So you saying I have to transform on use case or view model?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a mapper class to transform data in your use case and return domain object into your view
[more information and sample code](https://medium.com/@bkodirov/effective-mapping-android-a7c31ddce435)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and that's what I'm gonna do. But my question is,  where to map that? Domain? View model? Both?

Comment: In domain layer you must do that,
(Network -> Repository -> Domain)
and domain can see the network and repository files
and your view/view model can see just domain layer files

Answer (score 0):

Do it in `Use Case` layer, all of case the `ViewModel` shouldn't change any data from API, it only send it to `view`.

Answer (score 0):

In the repository you change the response to your Domain Entity, inside the ViewModel you change the Domain entity to View Entity, where the Domain is where your behavior is controlled for example you fetch data from API and then present in the view layer and you would like to add certain attributes for the view you map the domain to view and then if you would like to store things in database you map from view to domain and from domain to Database Entity